# How to prevent Eclipse from generating type annotations when assigning expression to local variable

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations

Assuming I have Java code like this:

```java
package test;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

public class Test {

    @NotNull
    public static Object object() {
        return new Object();
    }

    public static void test() {
        object();
    }
}

@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE_USE })
@interface NotNull {}
```

When I use the quick fix (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) action "Assign statement to new local variable" on the "object();" call, I'm getting this:

```java
public static void test() {
    @NotNull
    Object object = object();
}
```

I don't want the annotation in my client Java code as it's just noise for me. How can I prevent it from being generated all the time, and get this instead?

```java
public static void test() {
    Object object = object();
}
```

All of this only happens when the annotation has `@Target(TYPE_USE)`, and only when `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=8` or later in `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`

For the record, I've also filed [enhancement request 565463](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=565463).

(The real world API is declaring such annotations for better Kotlin interoperability (the JetBrains annotations are used), as Kotlin can use it to distinguish between `T` and `T?`, and avoid `T!`)

Comment: I can not reproduce this in Eclipse 2020-06 using [`org.jetbrains.annotations-1.5.0.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.realityforge.org.jetbrains.annotations/org.jetbrains.annotations/1.5.0) and different ways for _"use content assist to create a local variable from it"_ (which way did you take? please tell which keys you hit).

Comment: I don't know what fork that is, but I was using [the official distribution `org.jetbrains:annotations:19.0.0`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.jetbrains/annotations/19.0.0/jar). Anyway, the `@Target` element types are the same, so let's see how to reproduce it.

Comment: @howlger It seems related to the Eclipse's defaulting to `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.5` in `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`, in case of which type annotations are not supported yet, and thus the quick fix action doesn't work this way. As soon as compliance is upgraded to 8 or more, I can reproduce it again in a vanilla project. For the record, I'm using `Ctrl+1` on Windows with Eclipse 2020-06. Sorry, I should have called it quick fix, not content assist

Comment: Unfortunately this is still not reproducible, not with `annotations-19.0.0.jar` and not with Java 8 or Java 11 in a plain (non-Maven) Java project. Please show a single compilable class (rather than single lines of code) that can be used to reproduce this in a new plain Java project in a new workspace in Eclipse 2020-06.

Comment: @howlger: I've removed the dependency and created a self contained class. I've also uploaded a non-Maven, vanilla Java test project with a `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` file to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=565463#c1

Comment: Thanks for reporting the bug. But it seems to me to be a misconfiguration of the project rather than a bug (see my answer below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **`@NotNull`**, unwanted in your case, will be added if and only **if annotation-based null analysis is not enabled or misconfigured**.

In ***Project > Properies: Java > Compiler*** in the section ***Null analysis***:

1. Make sure the checkbox ***Enable annotation-based null analysis* is checked**
2. Instead of the checkbox ***Use default annotation for null specification*** being checked, click the ***Configure...*** link and **configure `test.NotNull`** (or `org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull`) as *'NonNull' annotation*

Please note, only **`ElementType.TYPE_USE` annotations** will be added. For methods annotated with an `ElementType.TYPE_USE` annotation (which cannot be added to `void` methods), the annotation **refers to the return type**, not to the method itself. In other words, you get an annotated object when calling such a method. For me, to add an *Use of a type* annotations to the type of a variable is the expected behavior.

It only becomes **unclear** for annotations like in your case that have **both targets, `ElementType.TYPE_USE` and `ElementType.METHOD`**. Does the annotation refer to the return type (so it make sense to add it) or does the method refer to the method itself (and therefore it should not be added)?

Please not also, in contrast to `org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull` `org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull` has no target `ElementType.METHOD`. How can a method declaration be `null`? What is the meaning of a `@NotNull` method? According to the [Javadoc of `org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.jetbrains/annotations/latest/org/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull.html) (*"... null value is forbidden to return (for methods)..."*), the target `ElementType.METHOD` seems to be added by mistake here, since it does not refer to the [method declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#METHOD).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I think this is good enough for the Stack Overflow question, so future visitors can use this to apply workarounds if needed. Whether or not this is desired can be further discussed in the bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=565463

Answer (score 0):

While the question is generic, the use-case behind the question is the jOOQ API, which starts adding the Jetbrains annotations in jOOQ 3.14 (see [#6244](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6244)) for better Kotlin interoperability, e.g.

```java
interface ResultQuery<R> {
  @NotNull Result<R> fetch();
  @Nullable R fetchOne();
}
```

In the case of jOOQ, the dependency on the annotations can be made optional/provided in Maven, or `static` in JPMS, such that ordinary Java client code doesn't see the annotation by default:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
    <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

The Kotlin compiler can still see it nevertheless:

```kotlin
val q: ResultQuery<R> = ...
q.fetch() // Result<R!>
q.fetchOne() // R?
```

If a third party out of your control is introducing the dependency, it can be excluded like this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
    
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: An optional Maven dependency prevents the `org.jetbrains` annotiations to be included in a fat JAR, but since they are `RetentionPolicy.CLASS` instead of `RetentionPolicy.SOURCE` the references to them are still in the bytecode, right? Is the Kotlin compiler not able to read null annotations from the source code like Eclipse can and does the Kotlin compiler require `org.jetbrains` null annotiations only? Besides, how is that related to your question?

Comment: @howlger: Of course, the bytecode inclusion is desired. Source code might not be available in a third party library. My original question was more specific than the current one. I'm just trying to help any future visitor here, who might have this problem and might find this workaround useful.

Comment: Eclipse can also read null analysis annotations from the Javadoc, so there is no need to pollute the bytecode with that. It's not clear to me what does this mean for the Java editor making the Maven dependency optional. I also didn't get it, why you do not want to configure the null annotations as null annotations (without configure them, you will not benefit from them).

Comment: @howlger: I'm all ears if you know a better solution that helps the Kotlin compiler infer nullability when working with a Java API.

Comment: I don't know if the Kotlin compiler is able to get null annotations from the source code or Javadoc ([external annotations don't seem to work either](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007696579-What-is-the-preferred-solution-for-distributing-external-annotations-)). Independent of that, in Eclipse null annotations should be configured as null annotations, so that these `TYPE_USE` annotations are implicitly handled (without the need to be explicitly present in the code where they are used).